# Calculating % differences in JupyterLab

Tags: python, pandas, jupyter

I am a new user to JupyterLab and attempting to calculate % differences between different data sets. I have sixteen data sets with 43 rows and 4 columns each. I am looking to calculate % differences between 2 data sets at a time and just between the last columns of each set. For example, this is what one of my data sets would look like.
date

```
1980-01-01       0        0     8
1981-01-01       0        0    10
1982-01-01       0        0     6
1983-01-01       0        0     4
(etc)
```

and

```
1980-01-01       0        0     8
1981-01-01       0        0    12
1982-01-01       0        0     2
1983-01-01       0        0     3
```

(etc)

So I am just looking to calculate the % differences between the last columns of each.

I have tried ratio functions, but am not coming up with any actual data and rather getting NaN for my newly generating charts.
Eventually I am hoping to graph the percent differences, but I'll cross that bridge when I get there. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Python's `zip` method to iterate thru two columns at once.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt   
diffs = [] 

# For each pair in your two dataframes, find % difference
for x, y in zip(dataframe1.column3, dataframe2.column3)
    sum = ( y + x ) / 2
    sum = ( y - x ) / sum
    
    diffs.append(sum)

# Plot line graph of percentage differences
plt.line(diffs)
```

Comment: Thank you for the response! I tried that after importing pandas to read my two data files and received this error message: 
Cell In[15], line 9
      7 # For each pair in your two dataframes, find % difference
      8 for x, y in zip(df5['MELT'] , dfCP['MELT']):
----> 9     sum = ( y + x ) / 2
     10     sum = ( y - x ) / sum
     12     diffs.append(sum)

TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'float' and 'str'

Comment: @naiyaluna You're trying to perform integer operations on non-integers (strings). That means some of your data in your dataframe are being read as strings. I would recommend this: use `dfCP.astype(int)` to convert every object in your dataframe to an integer. Alternatively, you can do `dfCP['last_column_name].astype(int)` if you don't want to mess up your date-times in the first column.